# How do I make a more lean conveyor belt?

Tags: polycount

[image]
[image]
In the render you see a blue conveyor belt, with flour on it. It has a knife edge(sharp turn, small radius) at each end. The trouble I'm having is that constructing a belt like this involves a few simple steps.

1. Create a curve path for the belt to follow - a 2D path with curved corners.
2. Add a plane to the scene, loop cut it until it conforms to the path.

The number of loop cuts I need to conform to the curve is very large. Is there a way I could do this with an extruded curve, and still have a UV map on the surface, while also being able to control the speed of the objects riding on the belt to coincide with the movement of the belt?

Thanks for any pointers.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bji8_da96GPnZEigvm_z0A5kzVZ2p6z3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm just wondering if you need to animate the geometry. Wouldn't it be enough to animate just the texture?

Comment: Good idea. I'll call this solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that animating the texture will be sufficient to get the same effect. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you find a good method of matching the animation speed to the objects on the conveyor you should [edit] it in. It would make a nice addition to this answer